# Tikz: Dimension Too Large

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions, matlab2tikz

I'm currently working on my Thesis using Overleaf and TexMaker. As I include a few high res images that i exported via matlab2tikz, they are very big and detailed. Recently I encountered an error in Overleaf where the dimension of my tikz .tex file was too large. However, Overleaf compiled using the following message:

> I can't work with sizes bigger than 19 feet. Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

However, TexMaker did not compile. Now I'm wondering whether there is a way to restrict the dimensions right in the .tex code ? Also, is there a way to shrink the dimension inside Matlab when using matlab2tikz ?

Thank you very very much !

Comment: This is more related to Matlab than LaTeX. You should rewrote Matlab routine so, that resulted image is adopted to presentation in Latex (image size should be a fraction of one feet ..., ). Since you not provide any code, we can't help you further.

Comment: Note that none of your number in calculations should exceed ±16383.99999 at any point.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Would you rather work with matlab2tikz or import the matlab figures as vector images ? Is there a recommendation ?

Comment: LaTeX can use .pdf .eps .ps .png .jpg .bmp with `\includegraphics{file name only without ext}` command of the `graphicx` package